# Draw on screen without it to be seen in a screenshot

Tags: c#, c++, windows, python-3.x, screenshot

Overall what I want to do is drawing a simple rectangle that will be drawn over everything on the screen (even say, over the task view in windows) in run time, and then when I take a screenshot of the screen in my program code, (I'm currently using mss in python) that the rectangle will not be captured in the image

I got this idea when I saw that the mouse cursor (when you take a simple screenshot) is invisible in the photo. (as shown)

[image]

I'd love to implement this code if possible in python or if not python then in c++ or even in c#

Comment: Hiding the mouse cursor is easy, you can disable it for as long as the screenshot takes, showing/hiding large boxes may cause a flicker effect, but you can use the same principle... Don't show the boxes while the screenshot code is running, then show them again after it is complete.

Comment: You could also try something with layers. For example, you might have a foreground layer with your rectangle on and then a background layer with your main image on. When you came to capture your image you'd only capture the contents of the background layer, ignoring the foreground and your rectangles.

Comment: alright, go ahead and implement it then...

Comment: @RonBeyer. Thanks it works.
Perhaps you also know how to draw above everything, as I asked also in the question?